# Can you verify this inequality $\binom {m^2} {m-1} \geq m^{m-1} \geq 2^{n/2}/n$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

$N \geq \binom {m^2} {m-1} \geq m^{m-1} \geq 2^{n/2}/n$, given $n = 2 m\log m$. Can you prove it? Where N is the number of subfunction.

This question is part of proof on finding lower bound on the number of sub functions for the element distinctness function in the book titled "Boolean Function Complexity" by Stasys Jukna. This function accepts an input $x \in \{0,1\}$ iff all the number on the domain are distinct. That is, assume the number of domain is $[m^2] = \{1,2,3,4, ...., m^2\} $ (we assume that m to be power of 2). 
Suppose we have  consecutive blocks $Y_1, Y_2,....,Y_m$. each block have $2\log m$ variables. So, the sum of all variables in all blocks is $n = 2 m \log m$

First, I try to generalize the binomial combination $\binom {m^2} {m-1} = \binom {m^2} {m^2-m+1} = \dfrac{m^2!}{(m-1)(m^2-n+1)!}= \dfrac{(m^2)\times (m^2-1) \times( m^2-2) \times .... \times (m^2-(n-2) \times (m^2-n+1)! }{(m-1)(m^2-n+1)!} = \dfrac{(m^2)\times (m^2-1) \times( m^2-2) \times ....\times (m^2-n+2)}{(m-1)}$

I try to make $\binom {m^2} {m-1}$ almost equal to $m^{m-1}$ but I don't see in my mind any idea that show this. any hence or property would be very nice.

*Every logarithm has a base of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can show that
$(m^2)\times (m^2-1) \times( m^2-2) \times ....\times (m^2-n+2)
> m^m
$,
this will prove the first inequality.

\begin{array}\\
P(m, n)
&=(m^2)\times (m^2-1) \times( m^2-2) \times ....\times (m^2-n+2)\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (m^2-k)\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (m+\sqrt{k})(m-\sqrt{k})\\
&>\prod_{k=0}^{n-2} (m+\sqrt{k})
\qquad\text{since } m > \sqrt{n}\\
&> m^{n-1}\\
&> m^{m-1}\\
\end{array}

with plenty to spare.

Comment: since $n = 2 m\log m$, then $n>m$ but you say $m>\sqrt{n}$ I wonder why do you assumed that way?

Comment: $m \approx (n/2)/log(n/2) > \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's clear now ..

Answer (score 1):

(Note:
I made a mistake which
was pointed out to me.
This now has the correction.)

For
$m^{m-1}
> 2^{n/2}/n
$
where
$n = 2m \log m
$.
(The mistake was here.
I had $2^n/n$
instead of
$2^{n/2}/n$.)

From
$n = 2m \log m
$,
$m
\approx (n/2)/\log(n/2)
$
plus smaller terms.

This is
$m^{m-1}(2m \log m)
> 2^{n/2}
$
or
$m^m
> 2^{n/2}/(\log m)
= 2^{n/2}/(\log(n/2)-\log\log(n/2)))
$.

$n = \log(m^{2m})
$,
so
$e^n
=m^{2m}
$
or
$m^m
=e^{n/2}
$.

Therefore,
you want
$e^{n/2}
= m^m
> 2^{n/2}/(\log(n/2)-\log\log(n/2)))
$.

This is true
for large $n$,
since
$e^{1/2}
> 2^{1/2}
$.

Comment: Let's see, I spent a lot of time to verify your proof: Argument 1. $n=\log m^{2m}$ by definition of log, then we can show that this equal to $2^n=m^{2m}$ instead of natural exponential that you show $e^n=m^{2m}$. since m is a power of 2, and log is with base 2, and so $2^n=m^{2m}$ is better bound. 2nd argument in the next coming comment. by the way, THANK you for you answering.

Comment: Argument 2. $m^{m-1} > 2^n/n$ implies $ m^{m-1} \times n > 2^n$ implies $ m^{m-1} \times 2 m \log m > 2^n$ implies $m^m \times 2 \log m > 2^n$ implies $m^m > 2^n/2\log m$ implies $m^m > 2^{n-1} \ \log m$, and you write $m^m > 2^{n}\ \log m$.

Comment: Argument 3. I tried to generalize the small terms, and I get $m = (n/2)/\prod_{i=0}^{k} (\log (S_i))$ where $i = \{0,1,2, ...k\}$ such that $S_i=(n/2)/\log n/2$ if you take $f = (n/2) / (\log (n/2))$ and $g = (n/2) / (\log (n/2) - \log \log (n/2))$ and take the difference you would see that g grows faster than f by a factor of 2. Thus, each term of $S_i$ is faster than the previous $S_{i-1}$ by almost a factor of 2.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, that is you wrote $ m^{m−1} \geq 2^n/n$ but the right one is $ m^{m−1} \geq 2^{n/2}/n$ and if you continue the formula, you see that this inequality is right. $m^{m-1} \geq 2^{n/2}/n$ implies $m^{m-1} \times n \geq 2^{n/2}$ implies $m^{m-1} \times 2 m \log m \geq 2^{n/2}$ implies $m^{m} \times 2 \log m \geq 2^{n/2}$ implies $m^{m} \geq 2^{m \log m - 1}/ \log m$ implies $m \log m \geq m \log m - 1/ \log \log m$ and therefore $\log \log m > $ constant. so this complete the proof.

Comment: You are right - my mistake. I'll fix that. Thanks.